# How can I convert a SymPy expression to NumPy?

Tags: python, numpy, sympy, converters

How can I convert a sympy expression to numpy code? For example, say I this was the code for the expression:

```
expression = 2 * x/y + 10 * sympy.exp(x) # Assuming that x and y are predefined from sympy.symbols
```

I would want to go from `expression` to this:

```py
np_expression = "np.dot(2, np.dot(x, np.linalg.pinv(y))) + np.dot(10, np.exp(x))"
```

Note that `x` and `y` are matrices, but we can assume the shapes will match

An example with real numbers would go like this:

```py
a = np.array([1,2],[3,4])
b = np.array([5,6],[7,8])

expression = 2 * a/b + 10 # These would be sympy symbols rather than numbers
```

and the result would be this:

```py
np_expression = "np.dot(2, np.dot(5, np.linalg.pinv(9))) + 10"
```

Comment: Can you provide sample values for x and y?

Comment: I could, but that would defeat the purpose. They're supposed to be sympy symbols.

Comment: Perhaps you're looking for the [subs](https://docs.sympy.org/latest/tutorial/basic_operations.html) method

Comment: I doesn't hurt to have a concrete example to help people get started on the question. I am testing if `autowrap` module could work here, and the distinction between matrices and scalars might be relevant, even though it is not apparent in the sympy expression.

Comment: Okay! I'll edit the question to add an example with real values

Comment: It looks like the example does not include the matrix exponent.

Comment: It is unlikely that you can get numpy source code automatically, e.g. a string `np_expression` in your example; however, it may be possible to compile a sympy expression so that it can be evaluated efficiently with numpy objects as inputs.

Comment: Is there some kind of parser that could be made to get the source code? I was taking a look at the `as_two_terms()` function inside of `sympy.core.mul.Mul`

Comment: `lambdify` creates a function from an expression.  It's largely a lexical substitution, without a "deep" understanding of `numpy`.

Comment: I tried that, @hpaulj, but it doesn't allow for dot product or `np.linalg.pinv`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
In [1]: expr = 2 *x/y + 10 * exp(x)
In [3]: f = lambdify((x,y), expr)
In [4]: help(f)
_lambdifygenerated(x, y)
    Created with lambdify. Signature:
    
    func(x, y)
    
    Expression:
    
    2*x/y + 10*exp(x)
    
    Source code:
    
    def _lambdifygenerated(x, y):
        return 2*x/y + 10*exp(x)
```

Which for specific inputs, array or otherwise:

```
In [5]: f(np.arange(1,5)[:,None], np.arange(1,4))
Out[5]: 
array([[ 29.18281828,  28.18281828,  27.84948495],
       [ 77.89056099,  75.89056099,  75.22389432],
       [206.85536923, 203.85536923, 202.85536923],
       [553.98150033, 549.98150033, 548.648167  ]])
In [6]: f(1,1)
Out[6]: 29.18281828459045
In [7]: f(2,3)
Out[7]: 75.22389432263984
In [8]: f(np.arange(1,4),np.arange(1,4))
Out[8]: array([ 29.18281828,  75.89056099, 202.85536923])
```

Normal array broadcasting rules apply.  Note that `x/y` is element-wise.  I'm not sure what `lambdify` will translate into `dot` and `inv` code.

trying your `numpy` code:

```
In [9]: np.dot(2, np.dot(2,np.linalg.pinv(3)))+10*np.exp(2)
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
LinAlgError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-9-6cae91f0e0f8> in <module>
----> 1 np.dot(2, np.dot(2,np.linalg.pinv(3)))+10*np.exp(2)
 ....

LinAlgError: 0-dimensional array given. Array must be at least two-dimensional
```

We have to change the `y` into a 2d array, e.g. `[[3]]`:

```
In [10]: np.dot(2, np.dot(2,np.linalg.pinv([[3]])))+10*np.exp(2)
Out[10]: array([[75.22389432]])
```